# Could Gaff have known about the unicorn without Deckard being a Replicant?

Tags: blade-runner, blade-runner-series

Or is that supposed to cinch it?

He appears to take the revelation rather calmly, doesn't he?

Comment: Not without reading the plot...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Opinions are divided](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Themes_in_Blade_Runner), even among the people with immediate creative input:

- Philip K. Dick wrote the character Deckard as a human in the original novel.
- Hampton Fancher (original screenwriter) has said that he wrote the character Deckard as a human, but wanted the film to suggest the possibility that he may be a replicant.
- Ridley Scott stated in an interview in 2002 that he considers Deckard a replicant.
- Harrison Ford considered Deckard to be human, at least originally (see details on Wiki).

Possible "human" explanations are that Deckard talked about the dream off-screen and Gaff somehow learned about it, or that it's a coincidence and Gaff intended it to symbolize Rachel.

If Deckard is a replicant, he may long have suspected it himself and is therefore not shocked.

Comment: Ridley Scott's 2002 interview: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7o0rvVxU0w

Comment: [Blade Runner FAQ entry](http://www.brmovie.com/FAQs/BR_FAQ_Influences.htm)